# MySQL calculate Latitude and Longitude radius

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a table with latitude(lat) and longitude(lng).

I want to get results with in a 35 kilometers (20 miles) radius.

I have a central latitude of "-38.156900" and longitude of "144.349150".

Using MySQL how can I work this out?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @JohnConde that is quite a different question, this is to find objects within a single point radius, rather than the distance between two fixed points.

Comment: @diagonalbatman that's the same, you just construct the `where` condition. If you look at the linked answer he's doing exactly the same: `having distance < 10`

Answer (score 3):

There is a really good guide to this [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL), which also talks about some of the performance aspects when doing geo-calculations in MySQL.

Comment: +1 as the source is very interesting, but link-only answers are not very good because the link might stop working. You should include the key messages from the linked resource into your answer.

Comment: Also the answer is behind a paywall